# Joining values of array. ${bar:1}

Tags: bash

I am trying to join values in an array, separated by a comma. I have found the answer to my problem, but I do not understand what the last line of the solution is doing. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=('foo bar' 'foo baz' 'bar baz')
bar=$(printf ",%s" "${foo[@]}")
bar=${bar:1}
```

I assume that the last line is making it so that there is no comma on the last element value. But...how is it doing it? What is that colon doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${bar:1}` expands to a substring of `bar`, starting at character #1 (which is the second character, since the count begins at zero) and continuing to the end of the string. So `bar=${bar:1}` removes the initial comma from `bar`.

(For more information, see the description of `${parameter:offset}` in [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This explains it. Feel like a fool for googling "bash colon." Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The `:` is substring expansion. It expands the substring of the parameter beginning at the specified offset. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter:offset}`
>   `${parameter:offset:length}`
>   **Substring Expansion.** Expands to up to `length` characters of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`. If `length` is omitted, expands to the substring of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`. ...